# Refactoring query using DISTINCT and JOINing table with a lot of records

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL v 11.6. I've read a lot of questions asking about how to optimize queries which are using DISTINCT. Mine is not that different, but despite the other questions where the people usually want's to keep the other part of the query and just somehow make DISTINCT ON faster, I am willing to rewrite the query with the sole purpose to make it as performent as possible. The current query is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name FROM app.source AS s
INNER JOIN app.index_value iv ON iv.source_id = s.id
INNER JOIN app.index i ON i.id = iv.index_id
INNER JOIN app.namespace AS ns ON i.namespace_id=ns.id
WHERE (SELECT TRUE FROM UNNEST(Array['Default']::CITEXT[]) AS nss WHERE ns.name ILIKE nss LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY s.name;
```

The `app.source` table contains about 800 records. The other tables are under 5000 recrods tops, but the `app.index_value` contains **35_420_354** (about 35 million records) which I guess causes the overall slow execution of the query.

The **EXPLAIN ANALYZE** returns this:
[image: The analyzer result]

I think that all relevent indexes are in place (maybe there can be made some small optimization) but I think that in order to get significant improvements in the time execution I need a better logic for the query.

The current execution time on a decent machine is 35~38 seconds.

Comment: `I think that all relevent indexes are in place` I think they are not. You should have added the relevant table definitions, including indexes to your question. [BTW: "index" is a bad name for a table]

Answer (score 3):

Your query is not using `DISTINCT ON`. It is merely using `DISTINCT` which is quite a different thing.

`SELECT DISTINCT` is indeed often an indicator for a oorly written query, because `DISTINCT` is used to remove duplicates and it is often the case tat the query creates those duplicates itself. The same is true for your query. You simply want all names where certain entries exist. So, use `EXISTS` (or `IN` for that matter).

### EXISTS

```
SELECT s.name 
FROM app.source AS s
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL 
  FROM app.index_value iv 
  JOIN app.index i ON i.id = iv.index_id
  JOIN app.namespace AS ns ON i.namespace_id = ns.id
  WHERE iv.source_id = s.id
  AND (SELECT TRUE FROM UNNEST(Array['Default']::CITEXT[]) AS nss WHERE ns.name ILIKE nss LIMIT 1)
)
ORDER BY s.name;
```

### IN

```
SELECT s.name 
FROM app.source AS s
WHERE s.id IN
(
  SELECT iv.source_id
  FROM app.index_value iv 
  JOIN app.index i ON i.id = iv.index_id
  JOIN app.namespace AS ns ON i.namespace_id = ns.id
  WHERE (SELECT TRUE FROM UNNEST(Array['Default']::CITEXT[]) AS nss WHERE ns.name ILIKE nss LIMIT 1)
)
ORDER BY s.name;
```

Thus we avoid creating an unnecessarily large intermediate result.

### Update 1

From the database side we can support queries with appropriate indexes. The only criteria used in your query that limits selected rows is the array lookup, though. This is probably slow, because the DBMS cannot use database indexes here as far as I know. And depending on the array content we can end up with zero app.namespace rows, few rows, many rows or even all rows. The DBMS cannot even make proper assumptions on know how many. From there we'll retrieve the related index and index_value rows. Again, these can be all or none. The DBMS could use indexes here or not. If it used indexes this would be very fast on small sets of rows and extremely slow on large data sets. And if it used full table scans and joined these via hash joins for instance, this would be the fastest approach for many rows and rather slow on few rows.

You can create indexes and see whether they get used or not. I suggest:

```
create index idx1 on app.index (namespace_id, id);
create index idx2 on app.index_value (index_id, source_id);
create index idx3 on app.source (id, name);
```

### Update 2

I am not versed with arrays. But t looks like you want to check if a matching condition exists. So again `EXISTS` might be a tad more appropriate:

```
  WHERE EXISTS
  (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM UNNEST(Array['Default']::CITEXT[]) AS nss
    WHERE ns.name ILIKE nss
  )
```

### Update 3

One more idea (I feel stupid now to have missed that): For each source we just look up whether there is at least one match. So maybe the DBMS starts with the `source` table and goes from that table to the next. For this we'd use the following indexes:

```
create index idx4 on index_value (source_id, index_id);
create index idx5 on index (id, namespace_id);
create index idx6 on namespace (id, name);
```

Just add them to your database and see what happens. You can always drop indexes again when you see the DBMS doesn't use them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In terms of time it gives about 5 second improvment but the execution time still remains around 30s. which is a lot. I could add the result from the analyzer but the post will get very big if I post lots of this. P.S Thanks for the comment that it's not DISTINCT ON, fixed.

Comment: @Leron_says_get_back_Monica do you have indexes for the FK's?

Comment: I thought about indexes, too, and have updated my answer acordingly. Problem is, the DBMS cannot know how many rows may match the array condition, so using indexes could make the query even particularly slow. It may be worth a try, though.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner As a matter of fact - no. What index would you recommend? Ahh I see you've already edited yout questions with some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: It was @wildplasser to mention indexes. As to my recommendation: Weave your way from table to table and you see what column(s) are used to find rows in a table and which column(s) are used then to get to the next table. That leads to the three indexes I mention at the end of my extended answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry it takes some time to try the thigns you proposed I will write soon with the results I get from the different changes

Comment: @ThorstenKettner So the change in namespace filtering and adding index on app.index_value is not helping. Currently I'm performing full vacuum so I'm waiting for it to finish and will add the other two indexes

Comment: Well, as mentioned, the DBMS is kind of helpless here anyway. It would be best, did the DBMS select the namespaces and then make a plan how to access the other tables, but things don't work this way. The DBMS makes an execution plan before it knows whether it is dealing with 0.001% of the table data or 99.999%, so it must come up with a plan that works for both scenarios and that may exclude using indexes.

Comment: If you know that the query will access a very small percentage of namespaces, say of 10000 namespaces never more than 3, then this would be a hint the DBMS could use. In that case we might apply a `FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY` at an appropriate place and thus tell the DBMS what to expect. But that would also *limit* the query to just 3 namespaces of course and make it less versatile.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner No, the assumption for namespaces can not be made. It's very likely that the number will be bigger and also very different for different users. But one thing I've noticed is that  a simple `select index_id from app.index_value;` takes more than a minute (longer than the query where it's JOIN-ed) how is it even possible?

Comment: I don't now. Maybe there's just many rows and memory is scarce? Then, this query will read all rows, so the table could be read sequentially. But maybe the DBMS thinks it can just read an index for that, which is smaller than the table, but then running through all those index branches takes longer than a mere sequential table scan would have taken? Or maybe still there are damaged sectors on your hard disk? ...

Comment: Well, I am using K8s cluster on Azure so I don't think above reasons apply. I'm thinking to use materialized view, what do you think? To filter the index_value data?

Comment: I don't know. As mentioned, your query can be used to access zero namespaces and zero result rows, or it can be used to select all namespaces with all indexes and all index values. The DBMS makes the same plan for both scenarios. Even if your final result is just five rows, the DBMS may read and join every single table row as a time stable brute-force method and you end up with a seemingly too long run time. Some queries just take time. I am not a PostgreSQL guy, so I am at my wits' end here.

Comment: Wait, ... I missed a point. With `EXISTS` / `IN` we suggest the DBMS takes the route from source to namespace, not vice versa. I've updated my answer with that last straw. Good luck with that :-)

Comment: the `id` fields are presumably primary keys, oe should at least be UNIQUE, IMHO. The FKs indeed need some supporting indexes. And the array is just what it is.

Comment: The fields in the index on `index_value` should definitely be in this order `(source_id, index_id)`